# How do I Program a button in Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I have recently started programming android apps (put simply, i have next to no experience with android programming). I have some experience with basic HTML, but not much beyond that. I have also been searching the internet for weeks on how to program one little button. None of them have worked. There are several XML layouts in my res folder, and all of them have buttons. What I need to know is how I can program a button in one of my XML layouts so that when it is pressed it takes me to another XML layout. However, if you answer this, please put a step-by-step guide, and tell me where to put the code including the placement in the code. My real problem, is the fact that i put in the code that tutorials tell me to, and it tells me that there are errors.

here are some of the websites i have tried:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen

[how to connect two activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292082/how-to-connect-two-activities)

[How to navigate from one screen to another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102050/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-screen)

http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=93#codesyntax_3

Comment: Please show us what exactly you have tried, so we can help you with your problem.

Comment: here are some of the links. eclipse always gives me errors!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/index.html

Comment: can you show us the error you are getting.

Comment: and sometimes it just brings up an alert that says: your project contains error(s) please fix them before running your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step by step guide:
http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/android101.pdf

Comment: i will try that, it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably start here 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: i looked at that, but i didnt really understand some of it.